# Final String in stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I create one table in SQL Server 2008, and test jdbc in java code.
In java code, the sql is like this:

```
static final String SQL = "select * from table1 where id=(?)"
```

And I use `Connection.prepareCall(SQL)` to get the result.
The question is I set the SQL sentence with final, why do it can set the value of id to the sentence in JDBC.

Comment: for one, you are not actually changing the String afterwards.

Comment: Whether the field you pass to a method as an argument is declared final or not does not matter - Java is pass-by-value, that means the method cannot change which object is stored in your field `SQL` anyway. On top of that, `String` is immutable, the method cannot change it.

Comment: What it *can* do is to use your input string as a template to create a new string containing the SQL statement it really needs to run - much like `printf` uses the format string passed to it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Typically the JDBC driver does not modify the SQL string for a PreparedStatement at all (and a CallableStatement is a PreparedStatement). It passes the SQL and the parameters separately to the database backend.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Feel free to answer.  I still think what I said about making the Java query string final is on the right track.

Comment: @Hulk's ask is great. thanks everyone's help.